# Is there a way to keep a derived object's data within a specific memory region defined in a base class?

Tags: c++, oop

Right now I'm using the following pattern:

```
class B
{
    int16_t b;
}

class C
{
    int32_t c1;
    int32_t c2;
    int32_t c3;
}
class A
{
    int8_t a;
    union
    {
        B b;
        C c;
    } params;
}
```

This way I'm able to declare an array of A and to have an option to hold B and C within this array. I use `a` as a type selector for a specific A.

I wonder if there is a way to do the same thing with inheritance?

Comment: Sounds like you want a [`variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/variant.html) type.

Comment: Sometimes a pattern like that might be useful, but most of the times I would argue it's a sign of a bad design. Can you please elaborate on *why* you need either `B` or `C` in the collection? What is the *actual* problem you try to solve with this?

Comment: Can you explain what is the use of defining class B and class C ? Are you intending to add new functionality or variables ?

Comment: why not make B,C derived from a base class, then use the base class pointer?

Comment: juanchopanza, thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: Some programmer dude, I agree, it looks a bit crappy, that's what makes me think of how to do the same thing but the other way. The actual problem is to have an array of a base class objects where I can place all the variety of derived objects. I have a worker thread that's iterating trough this array in an infinite loop and makes some calculations.

Comment: Rushikesh Deshpande, both of them. B and C are separate object with their own logics and variables.

Comment: zzn, that's what I'd like to do but I have to keep everything in a one continuous segment of memory with no pointer jumps.

Comment: @SergeB have you measured the performance with base class pointers? You can also allocate a blob of space and use placement new to construct your Bs and Cs contiguously